# Use of uninitialized value in string ne at. for array

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and I wrote a script for finding palindromic words like madam. However when I try to do the comparison to find out whether the word is a palindrome it gives me an error. Below is my code. I have put a comment on the problematic line. The error message is `Use of uninitialized value $forward[0] in string ne at...` and `Use of uninitialized value $backwards[0] in string ne at...`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";
print "<html> \n";
print "<head><title>Palindrome</title></head> \n";
print "<body><h1>Are the words palindromes?</h1> \n";
print "<hr /><pre>";

$query_string = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};

$_ = $query_string;

s/\W//gi;
s/\U$_/\L$_/gi;

@palindrome = split ( /=/, $_);
@backwards  = reverse ($palindrome[1]);
@forward    = reverse ($backwards[0]);
$sizePal    = @forward;

for ($i = 0; $i < $sizePal; $i++) {
    if ( $forward[$i] ne $backwards[$i] ) { # PROBLEMATIC LINE
        $result = "";
        last;
    }
    else {
        $result = "true";
    }
}

if ($result eq "true") {
    print "\n", $query_string, "is a palindrome \n";  
}
else {
    print  "\n", $query_string, "is a not palindrome \n";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always 'use strict;' and instead of `!# /usr/bin/perl -w`. Use `use warnings;`. It's a lot more flexible. I rewrote  your program:

Here's a few other hints:

- Don't use `$_` when you don't have to. There are problems with `$_` because of its *global* nature. It has to be used with `map` and `grep`, and people use it with `shift`, but most of the time, you end up having go assign it to something else anyway, so it doesn't do what it was suppose to do: Make your program *more readable*. In your case, you get an input, then assign it to `$_`. No need to do that.

This works just as well:

```
$query_string =~ s/\W//gi;
$query_string =~ s/\U$_/\L$_/gi;
```

- You're getting *arrays* and *scalars* mixed up.

This:

```
my @forward    = reverse ($backwards[0]);
```

is assuaging your string `$backwards[0]` `$forward[0]`. There is no `$forward[1]`. The entire string is being assigned to the first element of the array.

Maybe you want to do this:

```
my @forward = split //, reverse ($backwards[0]);
```

This splits the string `reverse ($backwards[0]` per letter, and puts each letter into `@forward`.

I'm not sure what the input is. Why are you splitting on `=`? Does the user enter a palindrome?

```
whatisit=tisitahw
```

Or like this:

```
madam, I am Adam.
```

If it is the latter, why go through all of the conniptions?

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);


print "Enter String: ";
chomp ( my $query_string= <STDIN> );

$query_string =~ s/[\W_]//g;

if ( lc $query_string eq lc reverse $query_string ) {
    say "Hey, that's a palindrome";
}
    say "No, it's not a palindrome";
}
```

I use `s/[\W_]//g` to remove all spaces, and other non-letter stuff. It does keep numbers. The `[\W_]` is needed because `\W` doesn't include underscores. The `g` on the end means do this as many times as necessary in the string and not just the first occurrence.

Then, all I have to do is compare the uppercase string to its reversed self. No need to step through an array. The `reverse` function handles everything for you. The only issue is that this is destructive because I munge the input string, so it doesn't match the user's input at the end of the program.

```
$ program.pl
String: Madam I am Adam.
No, it's not a palindrome
$

$ program.pl
String: Madam I'm Adam.
Hey, that's a palindrome
```

What you should do is make this a function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

print "Enter the string: ";
( my $string = chomp <STDIN> );

if ( palindrome( $string ) ) {
    say "Hey, $string is a palindrome";
}
    say "Sorry, $string is not a palindrome";
}

sub palindrome {
    my $palindrome = shift;
    $palindrome =~ s/[\W_]//g;

    if ( lc $palindrome ne lc reverse $palindrome ) {
        return;  # Not a palindrome
    }
    return $palindrome;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You assign a value only to one member of the array:

```
 @backwards = reverse ($palindrome[1]);
```

You probably meant

```
@backwards = reverse @palindrome;
```

But, why not just

```
print "$string ";
if ($string eq reverse $string) {
    print "is";
} else {
    print "is not";
}
print " a palindrome.";
```